# Unable to delete files in .NET API publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm stuck during publishing the API.
issue is when i check the deleting all existing files prior to publish.
then API Build successful but error in publish the API which is

> Deleting existing files...  Error deleting file 'JSONWebAPI'.   Unable
>   to delete 'JSONWebAPI'.   The process cannot access the file because
>   it is being used by another process. Publish failed. Target :
>   C:\\xxxxx\xxx\xxxx

[image]

if i unchecked that option "Deleting all existing files prior to publish" then published successful..
but what should i do for deleting all existing files prior to publish.

Comment: Don't keep them open but, did you try to first publish and THEN delete?

Comment: If unchecked this option. then it is published successfully.

Comment: And then files should be unlocked when asp.net process is discarded and a second publish may delete them.  However the problem is probably that you keep them open

Comment: i can't delete them manually in folder.  i'm beginner so i don't have enough knowledge of doing manually unless i see which exactly files are deleted . i'm following tutorial

Comment: will you please explain more precisely?

Comment: When you upload a new version the process running your site is unloaded. When it happens all not closed files are released. Now if you publish again you can delete them. BUT the problem is not this one. The problem is that, in your code, you open some files and you don't close them. That's the issue to fix (assuming you can't delete data files! Did you try to manually delete them?)

Comment: I got your point. Thanks mate. i'll close all files then try again

Comment: i'm confused to delete them manually. so i didn't delete

Comment: @MuhammadSaad Do you run Visual Studio as administrator? Had the same issue and that fixed it.

Comment: I have some issue. Running Visual Studio as administrator doesn't help